# mails forwarded by agents do not open in mail box in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

i have wrote an agent which works like this-

whenever my subordinates get any mail with an attachment; the agent runs and forwards that mail to our HR who can keep a track of all mails.

everything is working fine, but the issue occurs wen HR tries to open the mail..
he gets an notes error - ***"You are not authorized to access that database"***
even though he has an 'Person' 'Manager' accesss in the ACL.

What could have possibly went wrong?

Comment: Please mark your agent code as code. Right now we can not see your code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Mail Journalling and find out what it can do for you. Set it up on the Domino server, and add a rule that journals the mails you want.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the doclink and select properties. Check to see what you are actually linking to. I have seen common mistakes like this where the user is creating a doclink to their own mail file.